# WCF Service in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with connecting WCF Service and Windows Phone. I have a service with no source code (only publish on web) and I need to use it in Windows Phone 7 App.

I add a service reference in project, VS generated me file ServiceReferences.ClientConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding_IWcfMobilServices">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.www.com/WcfMobilServices.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding_IWcfMobilServices"
          contract="MobileService.IWcfMobilServices" name="HttpBinding_IWcfMobilServices"></endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When i call a service method:

```
public static void Login()
{
    var proxy = new MobileService.WcfMobilServicesClient();
    proxy.LoginAsync("loginName", "paswword");
    proxy.LoginCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
                //some code
        };
}
```

application in LoginCompleted throw me exception on a.Result :

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Content Type text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://www.www.com/WcfMobilServices.svc.  The client and service
>   bindings may be mismatched. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: NotFound.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   sendState)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at
>   W7App.MobileService.LoginCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()} System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
>   {System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException}

Any idea what's wrong?

I tried to change the Binding in config file to wsHttpBinding, but VS shows me a warning:

> The element 'bindings' has invalid child element 'wsHttpBinding'. List
>   of Possible elements expected: 'basicHttpBinding, CustomBinding'.

Thanks

Comment: If you proceed ahead with the warning what happens ? and this might be a possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250251/wcf-content-type-text-xml-charset-utf-8-was-not-supported-by-service

Comment: If i ignore warning in config, app throw me an error during creating instance of wcf class : Unrecognized element 'wsHttpBinding' in service reference configuration. Note that only a subset of the Windows Communication Foundation configuration functionality is available in Silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight / WP7 only support Basic HTTP unfortunately. Do you know if the end-point you are trying to connect to supports Basic HTTP Binding? It may be that it doesn't?

Comment: Really don't know. I have only describe of service methods and web address

Comment: I see that the endpoint address is "http://www.www.com/WcfMobilServices.svc". Is it the actual address of the WCF Service or is the service hosted in a machine inside a corporate network ?

Comment: @Ex_animo - Try creating a simple console application and connecting to the end-point. That will allow wsHttpBinding etc. Does that work? If so looks like the end-point doesn't support basicHttpBinding and means you might have a lot more work to do!

Comment: No... that is a fake address. Service is hosted inside corporate network. But i have no permission to look on server.

Comment: @Belogix - I am stupid..  You're right. I tried it and the service really only supports wsHttpBinding :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from our conversation. Silverlight / Windows Phone 7 **ONLY** supports `basicHttpBinding` and `CustomBinding`. By creating a console application you were able to connect using `wsHttpBinding`. So, your options are:

1. Ask for `basicHttpBinding` to be added to the end-point.
2. Create another WCF service that sits between the Windows Phone and other WCF service. That way you can connect with `basicHttpBinding` and then the intermediate WCF can use `wsHttpBinding` to connect to the other service.

Obviously, option 2 will be slower and add complication and hassle on any updates but unless option 1 is possible I don't think you have many other choices.