# Change Soap Request Header from text/xml to soap/xml for asmx webservice in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I need to call a webservice. I generated a proxy and invoked the method. But it keeps failing. Because the API is expecting soap/xml in the header whereas the proxy client generated in Visual studio is sending text/xml in header.

Question: Is it possible to change the value of the Content-Type header for a generated proxy client?

Comment: This may help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32e62554-dbe5-483b-830f-df1d2b22a845/client-found-response-content-type-of-but-expected-textxml?forum=wcf

Answer (score 3):

[Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250251/wcf-content-type-text-xml-charset-utf-8-was-not-supported-by-service)

> > this is usually a mismatch in the client/server bindings, where the
> >     message version in the service uses SOAP 1.2 (which expects
> >     application/soap+xml) and the version in the client uses SOAP 1.1
> >     (which sends text/xml). WSHttpBinding uses SOAP 1.2, BasicHttpBinding
> >     uses SOAP 1.1.
>
> It usually seems to be a wsHttpBinding on one side and a
>   basicHttpBinding on the other.

You can change the configuration on the client side to WSHttpBinding which uses SOAP 1.2 and it will affect the content type header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to change the binding to wsHttpBinding and it now sends `application/soap+xml`. But the endpoint is rejecting the request because it is expecting `soap/xml` explicitly

Comment: This saved me! Thanks! :-)